# how to count start hour of day, end hour of day, average hours per day in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
timestamps                                   values
2017-07-18 20:06:13                            12
2017-07-18 20:08:52                            34
2017-07-19 12:34:02                            123
2017-07-19 12:34:03                            34
2017-07-19 13:11:51                            33
2017-07-19 13:22:08                            76
2017-07-19 22:57:55                            44
2017-07-20 10:34:30                            443
2017-07-20 10:54:00                            32
2017-07-20 11:03:24                            22
2017-07-20 12:05:11                            44
2017-07-20 12:17:28                            323
2017-07-20 12:28:56                            33
```

timestamps column is datetime64[ns]. I need to find start hour of every day in timestamps column, every last hour in timestamps column and average count hours per day.

I also used groupby(), I need set index and group rows by day and hour:

```
df = df.set_index('timestamps')
df.groupby([df.index.day,df.index.hour]).count()
```

I got this result:

```
                             values 
timestamps timestamps         
18            20                  2 
19            12                  2 
              13                  2 
              22                  1 
20            10                  2 
              11                  1 
              12                  3
```

I can't extract start hour of every day, every last hourn and average count hours per day in index of dataframe. How can I get this? Thx for any suggestions.

Comment: what is the expected output? can you add the same too?

Comment: @anky_91 I expected to extract just a number, which I cane append in list or numpy array

Comment: Assuming I understood you, you want to also include the count of missing days and hours as 0, right? If not, you will need to clarify your question.

Comment: @cs95 Yes, you are right

Comment: Ok, can you please edit your question and take a look at the answers below? If one of them answers your question, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can try this:

```
df['timestamps'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamps'])
df['hour'] = df['timestamps'].dt.hour
df.groupby(df['timestamps'].dt.day).agg({'hour': ['min', 'max', 'mean']}) \
                                   .stack(level=0).droplevel(1)


        min max mean
timestamps          
18      20  20  20.000000
19      12  22  14.400000
20      10  12  11.166667
```

Answer (score 1):

To present more instructive example, I defined the test DataFrame
with dates from **different** months (also from August):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ '2017-07-18 20:06:13',  12 ],
    [ '2017-07-18 20:08:52',  34 ],
    [ '2017-07-19 12:34:02', 123 ],
    [ '2017-07-19 12:34:03',  34 ],
    [ '2017-07-19 13:11:51',  33 ],
    [ '2017-07-19 13:22:08',  76 ],
    [ '2017-07-19 22:57:55',  44 ],
    [ '2017-07-20 10:34:30', 443 ],
    [ '2017-07-20 10:54:00',  32 ],
    [ '2017-07-20 11:03:24',  22 ],
    [ '2017-07-20 12:05:11',  44 ],
    [ '2017-07-20 12:17:28', 323 ],
    [ '2017-07-20 12:28:56',  33 ],
    [ '2017-08-20 11:01:00', 122 ],
    [ '2017-08-20 13:55:58',  44 ]],
    columns=['timestamps', 'values'])
df['timestamps'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamps'])
```

To compute the values you need, define a function to compute
the number of hours between *min* and *max* time in particular day:

```
def fn(row):
    return (row['max'] - row['min']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
```

Then run:

```
dayLimits = df.groupby(df.timestamps.dt.floor('d'))\
    .agg({'timestamps': [min, max]})
dayLimits.columns = dayLimits.columns.droplevel(0)
dayLimits['hrs'] = dayLimits.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

This code:

- groups *df* by date,
- from each group takes min and max timestamp,
- drops the top level of column multiindex,
- generates *hrs* column, applying the above defined function.

The result, for my test data, is:

```
                           min                 max        hrs
timestamps                                                   
2017-07-18 2017-07-18 20:06:13 2017-07-18 20:08:52   0.044167
2017-07-19 2017-07-19 12:34:02 2017-07-19 22:57:55  10.398056
2017-07-20 2017-07-20 10:34:30 2017-07-20 12:28:56   1.907222
2017-08-20 2017-08-20 11:01:00 2017-08-20 13:55:58   2.916111
```

And now, having number of hours in each day, the average number of
hours per day, you can compute as:

```
dayLimits.hrs.mean()
```

And finally a note concerning one of other answers:

Grouping by *dt.day* is wrong, because e.g. rows from 20-th day in
**each month** are members of **the same group**.

If you have dates from a single month, it is not obvious, but
try this code on **my** test DataFrame, so you will see it.

## Edit

Names of columns should be other than reserved words of *Python*
or e.g. function names.

So other solution, taking the above into account, can be:

```
dayLimits = df.groupby(df.timestamps.dt.floor('d'))\
    .agg({'timestamps': [min, max]})
dayLimits.columns = ['tmin', 'tmax']
dayLimits['hrs'] = dayLimits.apply(lambda row:
    (row.tmax - row.tmin) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h'), axis=1)
```

The result is different only in column names.